# Can't update via the terminal

Tags: updates, software-center, uninstall, playonlinux

Hi having problems with updating ubuntu 14.01

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Gives me the following.

> E: Typen »!DOCTYPE« er ukendt på linje 1 i kildelisten /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
>   E: Listen med kilder kunne ikke læses.

Translated:

E: Type >>!DOCTYPE<< is unknown on line 1 in sourcelist /etc/apt/sources.listd/playonlinux.list
E: list with sources couldn't be read.

After the >> in the code this symbol (<), without the () but if I write it in, the block disappears in here... (hope it makes sense)

I'm aware that it maybe would help to delete playonlinux, but my software-center won't open and I don't know any other way of deleting the program..

```
sudo rm playonlinux
```

doesn't work, don't know if I'm using the code correct..

Kind regards - The rook

Comment: There is no 14.01; if you mean 14.10 then still in development and not supported on this site but you could ask on [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions) or the [Ubuntu Forums: Development version](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427) where the development version is supported. But, unless you have a good reason to use 14.10 I would use 14.04 instead which is stable and fully supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an erroneous repo file. To fix it, type these commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E0F72778C4676186
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo nano  /etc/apt/sources.listd/playonlinux.list
```

Then remove that error from line then save & exit.

Then try with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

else

as you already deleted playonlinux ,

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.listd/playonlinux.list
```

Good luck.